# Prove a simple equality in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $S$, and n-dimension vectors $A$ and $B$, prove:

$$(SA)^TB=(SB)^TA$$

---

What I've tried:

Since the result is a scalar, transposition won't change the value

$$(SB)^TA=((SB)^TA)^T=A^T(SB)$$

and

$$(SA)^TB=(A^TS)B$$

and I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Hint: Matrix products are associative.

Comment: Your proof is missing one step. Just apply the invariance under transpose on $A^T(SB)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is that, for two matrices U, V, you have $(UV)^T=V^TU^T$ (if their shape allow the product, of course). And, if S is symmetric, $S^T=S$. Also, a vector is viewed as a column matrix.

First,
$$(SA)^TB=A^TS^TB=A^TSB$$
$$(SB)^TA=B^TS^TA=B^TSA$$

Now, transpose the latter:
$$(B^TSA)^T=A^TS^TB=A^TSB$$

By the way, these are all scalars, since A and B are vectors.